# Share different text depending on the share target

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

My app shares some text describing my current GPS location - something like:

> I am at 33° 58' S 18° 27' W.

I am using the `ShareActionProvider` as is the current "correct" way to do this. And the sharing is working 100%, as expected.

Life would be good, if the client was happy...

---

The client is not happy.

---

The client would like to be able to share my location differently in email, compared to sms.

e.g.

> ```
> I am at a new location:
> - Latitude: 33 58' S
> - Longitude: 18 27' W
> ```

---

- I believe this is not possible with `ShareActionProvider` - is that
  correct?
- I believe this is not possible by sending out a share
  intent.

**What are my options for implementing this?**

Must I create a custom Share view, populating it by querying the system for all apps that accept Share intents?

---

(Note: my beliefs are that the client should accept default Android share behaviour, however this is a real-world situation where the client's needs must be considered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, achieving this is not possible with the standard `ShareActionProvider`. It looks like you will have to roll out a custom `ShareActionProvider` to achieve what you want, as stated here:

[Detecting sharer app when using share action provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539812/detecting-sharer-app-when-using-share-action-provider/15539927#15539927)