# Detecting sharer app when using share action provider

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

Is there any way I can detect which sharer app is selected when using share action provider,so that I can send different messages for different apps? 
I am using following method for share action provider,

```
mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share).getActionProvider();

        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());
```

and intent,

```
 public Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){
              String message = Fname + Mobileno + Homeno + Workmail + Homemail
                + Gtalk + Skype + Address + Company + Title + Website;
      Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
              shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message); 


         return shareIntent; 


    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

The simplest solution is:

```
@Override
public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source, Intent intent) {
  String shareTarget = intent.getComponent().getPackageName();
  ...
}
```

No need to copy files or anything.

---

Copy some files from either the Android source, or ActionBarSherlock, if you happen to use the latter:

- ActivityChooserModel.java
- ActivityChooserView.java
- ShareActionProvider.java

Make sure you reference these files, not the original ones from your app.

In *ActivityChooserModel.java*, modify this:

```
if (mActivityChoserModelPolicy != null) {
  ResolveInfo info = getActivity(index);
  choiceIntent.putExtra("user_selected_activity", (info.activityInfo != null) ? info.activityInfo.packageName : info.serviceInfo.packageName);
  final boolean handled = mActivityChoserModelPolicy.onChooseActivity(this, choiceIntent);
  if (handled)
    return null;
}
```

and it will store the package name of the selected activity into the intent. You can then read it in your handler:

```
@Override
public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source, Intent intent) {
  String shareTarget = intent.getStringExtra("user_selected_activity");
  ...
}
```

and decide what to handle differently depending on the activity selected.

Comment: But Android developers says Modifying the intent is not permitted and any changes to the latter will be ignored. For reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener.html#onShareTargetSelected%28android.widget.ShareActionProvider,%20android.content.Intent%29

Comment: In these cases, you generally don't want to modify the intent itself, just to set the extras differently (eg. send HTML to apps that handle it, text to those who don't).

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
myShareActionProvider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(new ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source, Intent intent) {
                String shareTarget = intent.getComponent().getPackageName();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Here we works but, we can not modify intent here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener.html#onShareTargetSelected%28android.widget.ShareActionProvider,%20android.content.Intent%29

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like it.  But there's nothing stopping you from copying and pasting it into your project and modifying it as you see fit.

Comment: If you have installed "Sources for Android SDK" using the Android SDK Manager, you can right-click ShareActionProvider and select "Open Declaration" to see the source code.  ShareActionProvider doesn't do anything you can't do yourself, so if you want you could copy & paste the code into your own class and modify it.